# Incremental publishing on Eclipse Juno and GlassFish 3.1.2.2

Tags: deployment, glassfish, eclipse-juno

After updating my Eclipse to Juno and latest GlassFish to 3.1.2.2 I've lost the option to incremental deploy applications from the servers tab (I see the server there and deploys and runs my Java EE apps OK but now if I change any xhtml file I need to redeploy all the app).

I used to have a menu in the deployed application inside the servers where I could do a full deploy or incremental deploy, which I used a lot whenever I did any minor change.

I use an external Glassfish, not the internal runtime and I'm using MacOS Lion.